Can we overlay ARView and ARSCNView?
I want to use some functionalities from ARView (RealityKit) such as the MultiPeer API, loading usdz models etc. I also want to use some functionalities from ARSCNView (ARKit + SceneKit) such as interactions with real-world objects or object recognition. Is it possible to have ARView and ARSCNView overlaid in the same storyboard? I assume both ARSCNView and ARView can share the same ARSession since they both rely on the device’s camera and motion sensors.
Currently, I'm doing something like below.
import UIKit
import ARKit
import RealityKit
import SceneKit

class ARViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView! // From storyboard, this will be on top of ARSCNView
    var arSCNView: ARSCNView! // Added programmatically

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Step 1: Setup ARSCNView programmatically
        arSCNView = ARSCNView()
        
        // Step 2: Add ARSCNView as the background layer
        view.addSubview(arSCNView)
        
        // Step 3: Set constraints to make ARSCNView fill the screen
        arSCNView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            arSCNView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            arSCNView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            arSCNView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            arSCNView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        
        // Step 4: Bring ARView to the front
        view.bringSubviewToFront(arView)
        
        // Step 5: Configure ARSCNView's session
        let sceneKitConfig = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        sceneKitConfig.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
        arSCNView.session.run(sceneKitConfig)
        
        // Step 6: Share the ARSession between ARSCNView and ARView
        arSCNView.session = arView.session

        // Optional: Set ARSCNView delegate
        arSCNView.delegate = self
        
        // Rest of setup code
    }
    
    // Other methods remain unchanged
}


However, the VisionViewController extending the above ARViewController seems cannot be instantiated as the debugging message in viewDidLoad() cannot be printed out.
class VisionViewController: ARViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print("loading arsceneview") //This debugging message cannot be printed out
        super.viewDidLoad()
        arSCNView.delegate = self
        arSCNView.showsStatistics = true
        arSCNView.debugOptions = .showBoundingBoxes
        arSCNView.session.delegate = self
    }
    
    override func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
       //implementations
    }
    // other methods

}

Is it possible to use both ARView and ARSCNView at the same time? Thank you!
I tried to have the following statements in ARViewController. However, the VisionViewController is still not instantiated.
let viewController = VisionViewController()
self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

I also tried to bring ARView to the front with view.bringSubviewToFront(arView)
I also looked into some related post. However, I want to use CoreML model for object detection instead of pre-scanned 3D objects. I don't know if it is possible to have pre-trained CoreML model involved.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arreferenceobject
Can RealityKit and and SceneKit be used together?
